# Can one find uncountably many $T_x \subseteq \mathbb N$, any two of which have an empty intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is this :

Can one find uncountably many $T_x \subseteq \mathbb N$, any two of which have an empty intersection.

I am currently reading an introductory text in Set Theory (Stillwell; The Real Numbers - An Introduction to Set Theory and Analysis).  My question is a variation on one of the exercises appearing in the section entitled The Uncountability of $\mathbb R$.  The original exercise requires that we find uncountably many $T_x$, any two of which have a finite intersection.  I have solved this, together with the variation requiring any two of which have a countably infinite intersection.  This leave the case of empty intersection posed here.

The approach I am trying is outlined here :

Let $\mathcal C$ be an uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$.  For $x \in \mathcal C$, let $t_x = ( a_1, a_2, ... )$ be a sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$.  Then we wish to choose $\mathcal C$ and $t_x$ so that whenever $x \neq y$, we have $t_x$ and $t_y$ sharing no common elements.  We can then use an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ to encode the $t_x$ as subsets of $\mathbb N$.

This is roughly the same approach I have taken to solving the original problem.  However, unlike the original problem where $\mathcal C$ can be any uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ and $t_x$ any convergent sequence, it appears that we now need to specify individual sequences $t_x$ for each $x$, and we probably need to choose $\mathcal C$ very carefully.  I have been working with $\mathcal C$ = Cantor's Ternary Set in the naive believe that a nowhere-dense set may leave enough room for our sequences to avoid intersecting.  My textbook gives no formal treatment of dense or nowhere-dense sets, but from what I have read on wikipedia, I think I may be barking up the wrong tree here.

So, is it possible?  If so, any suggestions for a better approach?

Comment: Obviously this is not possible. No point in a $T_x$ is in any other $T_y$, so the union of all the $T_x$ would be uncountable.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I'm not sure that I understand your comment.  How does the uncountability of the union prevent the $T_x$ having an empty intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not possible. Simply note that if $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint and non-empty sets, then $A_i\mapsto\min A_i$ is an injection into $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That's very clever, as well a plainly obvious now that you have pointed it out.  Thanks Asaf.